# How can you get Power Query/Excel to separate and associate two unique IDs from the same column?

Tags: excel, vba, powerbi, powerquery, m

I have a dataset that exports with a single column including personnel IDs and job IDs.

I want to use Power Query separate Person_ID into one column and Job_ID into another column. People are associated with the job that appears closest above them. Job IDs are a 6-character text string, Person IDs are 9 character.  The same Job_ID can apply to multiple people, but Person_ID is unique (only one job per person, multiple people for some jobs).

Example data structure:

[image]

Hope someone's got something!

Comment: I'm too new to add an image, maybe this will help... https://photos.app.goo.gl/MLcjAsJLhwT8XCaaA

Comment: What have you researched / tried so far, and why is it not working?

Comment: I was looking up ways to use Text.Length and conditionals to determine which number is which type to start, but was having trouble with the syntax.  Then I need something like offset to check the values in the cells above each reference cell (person ID) to find the nearest job ID. These values would have to copy or pivot into a new column.  The last step would be filtering the reference column so it's just person ID, and the new column just job ID.  I bet there's an easier way. I could probably make a VBA macro for this, but I'd prefer to use power query/M since that's what's getting the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step by step

Highlight input data

Data...From Table/Range...  do not check [] my table has headers

Add Column...Custom Column... using column name Custom,  with formula

```
Text.Length([Column1])
```

Add Column...Custom Column... using column name Custom.1,  with formula

```
if [Custom]=6 then [Column1] else null
```

Click on Custom.1 column, right click and do fill...down...

Use arrow next to Custom column and uncheck [] 6 leaving just [x]11

Click column Custom, right click and choose remove columns

file...close and load

Code produced:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each Text.Length([Column1])),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom.1", each if [Custom]=6 then [Column1] else null),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom1",{"Custom.1"}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filled Down", each ([Custom] =11)),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Custom"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```

Comment: Just tested it out, great solution! This is going to save me a ton of time at work.  Thanks so much!